# JAVA - Сдвиг целой строки двухмерного массива в конец

Tags: java

В моем коде определяется самое маленькое число массива и обнуляется вся строка чисел, которой принадлежит это число. Нужно сдвинуть строку нулей в самый конец массива, чтоб строка нулей была последней. Как сдвинуть одно число - понятно, но не доходит как аналогичное провернуть с целой строкой.

Код:

```
public static void zeroAndResult(long [][] arr) {

    int row = 0;
    int nElems = 7;
    System.out.println("\n" + "Новый массив:" + "\n");

    long min = arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (min > arr[i][j]) {
                min = arr[i][j];
                row = i;
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Обнуляем
        if (i == row) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
                //arr[i][j] = arr[(arr.length-1) - i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Выводим массив
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: А что делать с последней строкой, которая уже существует и чем-то заполнена?

Comment: Весь массив заполнен рандомными числами. Если сдвигать строку нулей в самый конец, то последняя строка станет предпоследней, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Например, у нас массив с обнулением строки: {1234}, {0000}, {1144}, {5135}. В результате операции должно получится {1234}, {1144}, {5135}, {0000}

Comment: сейчас напишу пример, как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего хочу отметить особенность циклов вашего кода, а именно то, что следующий код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (min > arr[i][j]) {
            min = arr[i][j];
            row = i;
        }
    }
}
```

будет работать, если размер вашего двумерного массива будет одинаковым, т.е. 4х4, 5х5, но сломается, например, в случае 3х5.
Для того, чтобы избавиться от этой *особенности*, рекомендую формировать циклы следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (min > arr[i][j]) {
            min = arr[i][j];
            row = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь собственно к вашей задаче. Насколько я понимаю, вам необходимо найти наименьший элемент в массиве, занулить строку, в которой находится этот элемент, сдвинуть все строки на место нулевой, а нулевую поместить в конец.

Исходный массив:

```
{1,1,1,1}  
{2,2,0,2}  
{3,3,3,3}  
{4,4,4,4}
```

Промежуточный этап:

```
{1,1,1,1}  
{0,0,0,0}  
{3,3,3,3}  
{4,4,4,4}
```

Желаемый результат:

```
{1,1,1,1}  
{3,3,3,3}  
{4,4,4,4}  
{0,0,0,0}
```

Для достижения цели предлагаю использовать метод `System.arraycopy` и следующий алгоритм:

1. Находим минимальный элемент массива, запоминаем строку. Это собственно то, что у вас уже сделано.
2. Вместо того, чтобы обнулять нужную строку, начинаем смещать следующую строку наверх. Делаем это до тех пор, пока не дойдем до последней строки.
3. После перемещения последней строки вверх, она становится предпоследней, а последнюю мы зануляем.

### Теперь перейдем к реализации.

**Шаг 1.** То, что у вас уже реализовано.

```
long[][] arr = new long[][]{{1,1,1,1}, {2,0,2,2}, {3,3,3,3}, {4,4,4,4}};

int row = 0;
System.out.println("\n" + "Новый массив:" + "\n");

long min = arr[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (min > arr[i][j]) {
            min = arr[i][j];
            row = i;
        }
    }
}
```

**Шаг 2.** Определяем количество шагов, необходимых для сдвига и сдвигаем каждую строку в цикле наверх.

```
int steps = arr.length - row - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(arr[row + i + 1], 0, arr[row + i], 0, arr[row + i + 1].length);
}
```

Метод `System.arraycopy` принимает на вход следующие параметры (слева направо):

- src - массив источник;
- srcPos - позиция начала копирования (куда копируем);
- dest - массив назначения;
- destPos - позиция начала копирования (откуда начинаем копировать);
- length - количество копируемых элементов.

Подробнее про [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

**Шаг 3.** На этом шаге мы имеем следующую структуру:

```
{1,1,1,1}  
{3,3,3,3}  
{4,4,4,4}  
{4,4,4,4}
```

Все, что нам нужно, это занулить последнюю строку:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr[arr.length - 1].length; i++) {
    arr[arr.length - 1][i] = 0;
}
```

Для того, чтобы убедиться, что все прошло успешно, воспользуемся последней частью вашего кода и выведем массив на экран:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Выводим массив
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

На экране мы увидим:

```
1 1 1 1 
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4  
0 0 0 0
```